# I am trying to find the limit of P(x)

Tags: limits, functions, infinity

When I am looking for a $\lim\limits_{x \to -1} P(x)$ 
where P(x)$= \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left( \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} - \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}\right) $ do I have to ignore a summation sign sigma and dealing with it like this $ \
\lim\limits_{x \to -1}(\arctan\sqrt{n+x} - \arctan \sqrt{n+1}  )  $ ?

Comment: Is the summation really starting at $n=1$?

Comment: $ P(x)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x-1}{(k+x+1)\sqrt{k+1}+(k+2)\sqrt{k+x}}\right) $

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\color{red}{-\frac{3\pi}{4}}$$
since the LHS is a telescopic series. Here I assumed $\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{0}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

We are allowed to switch the limit and the integral since for any fixed $x$ $\left|\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}\right|$ behaves like $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ for large $n$s.

Comment: While I agree with the result, isn't some justification needed for *why* it's legitimate to switch sum and limit here?

Comment: @ClementC.: you are right, but absolute convergence is clearly enough. For a fixed $x$, $\left|\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}\right|$ behaves like $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$.

Comment: (sorry if it's obvious) I thought that absolute convergence for a series of functions required to prove uniform convergence of $\sum_n \lvert f_n \rvert$ (the above only gives pointwise, doesn't it?) It seems actually easier to show directly normal convergence on $[-1,0]$ (say)

Comment: Anyway you like, the limit/series exchange is legit.

Answer (score 0):

We write $P(-1^+)$ as

$$\begin{align}
P(-1^+)&=\arctan(1/\sqrt{2})-\pi/2+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\arctan \sqrt{n-1}-\arctan \sqrt{n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\arctan \sqrt{n-1}-\arctan \sqrt{n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\arctan(0)+\arctan(1)-\arctan(N-1)-\arctan(N)\right)\\\\
&=0+\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\\\\
&=-\frac{3\pi}{4}
\end{align}$$